# Ran out of inodes on NFS

Tags: linux, nfs, inode

I have a RHEL 6 box with an NFS mount, mounted using autofs.  I copied a big folder, with a lot of small files there, and used up all of my inodes, but I still have 80% of my storage space left, this is a real pain!  What is the easiest way out of this?  I'd prefer not to have to remove anything from the NFS mount, and resizing isn't really an option right now.  Is there some mount options or some other trick to be able use this NFS mount?

Comment: If you really need to use this partition, you have to free up the small files that are irrelevant or move them to another partition having large number of inodes. Apart from that, the only option I can see is `tune2fs` but you do not want to do that.

Comment: Can't you collect some of the files into tarbals and then delete them? You don't even need to compress if you don't want to.

Comment: The solution here may help you identify which directories contain the most files contributing to your issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/howto-free-inode-usage

Comment: So I guess there is no mount option that helps me out here or any special trick.  This is the same as any other filesystem running out of inodes I guess.